# ExtJS and Google Maps - LoadMask not centered after upgrading from ExtJS 4.1.1 to 4.2.0

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a simple ExtJS component that I am using to display a map using google maps.  Upon upgrading from ExtJS 4.1.1 to 4.2.0 my loadmasks for this component are not centered correctly.

See the following jsFiddle links for demo.

Using ExtJS 4.1.1: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qVYq7/)

Using ExtJS 4.2.0: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QXjyh/1/)

To see what I'm talking about, Add Map, then Apply Loadmask.  Loadmask is centered in the first example, yet out of position in the second.  Note that if you apply loadmask before adding map in the second example the loadmask displays correctly.

Is this a bug?  Should I be applying the loadmask differently or perhaps rendering the google maps object differently?  Thanks.

Basic code I'm using for examples:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
        height:300,
        width:300,
        title:'Using ExtJS 4.x.x',
        id: 'gmap-win'
    }).show();

    Ext.create('Ext.button.Button',{
        text:'Add Map',
        renderTo:'btn',
        handler: function(){
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 2,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            };
            new google.maps.Map(Ext.getCmp('gmap-win').body.dom, myOptions);
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.button.Button',{
        text:'Apply loadmask',
        renderTo:'btn1',
        handler: function(){
            Ext.getCmp('gmap-win').setLoading(true);
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.button.Button',{
        text:'Remove loadmask',
        renderTo:'btn2',
        handler: function(){
            Ext.getCmp('gmap-win').setLoading(false);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ext 4.2 apparently markup was changed for window. 
In 4.1.1 body of window looks like this:

```
<div id="gmap-win-body" class="x-window-body x-window-body-default x-closable x-window-body-closable x-window-body-default-closable x-window-body-default x-window-body-default-closable" style="width: 290px; height: 270px; left: 0px; top: 20px;">
    <div id="gmap-win-clearEl" class="x-clear" role="presentation"></div>
</div>
```

while in 4.2 like this:

```
<div id="gmap-win-body" class="x-window-body x-window-body-default x-closable x-window-body-closable x-window-body-default-closable x-window-body-default x-window-body-default-closable x-resizable x-window-body-resizable x-window-body-default-resizable" style="width: 290px; height: 270px; left: 0px; top: 20px;">
    <span id="gmap-win-outerCt" style="display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; height: 100%;">
        <div id="gmap-win-innerCt" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;" class=""></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

You render map into `body`, so after map is created markup looks similiar. The difference is that, in 4.2 centering function uses `innerCt`, which is missing after map is rendered.

One way to fix that is to add component into window in which map will be rendered:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
    height:300,
    width:300,
    title:'Using ExtJS 4.2.0',
    id: 'gmap-win',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
        { xtype: 'box', itemId: 'map' }
    ]
}).show();

[...]

new google.maps.Map(Ext.getCmp('gmap-win').getComponent('map').el.dom, myOptions);
```

working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Ksy/2/

Comment: Thanks!  Do you think this is a bug?

Comment: No I don't. There was some changes in `Ext.layout.container.Auto` layout, and that layout is responsible for markup differences. In 4.1.1 there is only `clearEl` under container, which is there only to apply `clear: both` style. On the other hand, in 4.2 there are `outerCt` and `innerCt`, which are there for a reason. Rendering map directly into `body` replaces it's content and therefore might cause some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Lolo suggested solving this by placing a child panel inside the main panel and rendering the google maps object to that.  That works.  Another way to solve it though is to simply create a hidden child panel.  Not sure why exactly that fixes the problem, but it does.

```
 Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
        height:300,
        width:300,
        title:'Using ExtJS 4.2.0',
        id: 'gmap-win',
        layout:'fit',     /// ADDED
        items:[{hidden:true}]  /// ADDED
    }).show();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4w9zd3je/)